# How to add trivial OpenGL functionality to Xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin, opentk

Can anyone please help with the following?

I have a trivial Xamarin forms app working and I want to add an OpenTK view.

The following works fine:

In my MainPage.xaml.cs I have the following event handler for a button which spawns an empty OpenTK view on each click:

```
private void OnXAMLButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var view = new OpenGLView { HasRenderLoop = true };

            view.HeightRequest = 300;
            view.WidthRequest = 300;

            view.OnDisplay = r =>
            {
                //GL.ClearColor(red, green, blue, 1.0f);
            };

            m_SL.Children.Add(view);
        }
```

(where m_SL is the name of my StackLayout).

I get a new black window on each click. Great.

Now, see that commented-out line, that's because the value GL is undefined.

This code is from the simple example here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.openglview?view=xamarin-forms

I see at the top of that example there is the following:

using OpenTK.Graphics.ES30;

But I cannot include this, OpenTK is not recognized as a namespace. I expected to have to add it as a reference, but how?

I can add a reference to it in my .Android project so that I can add the above using statement in my MainActivity.cs page but that is not where it belongs (although I see that I then have GL defined, so this proves that I need to add these using statements to my MainPage.xaml.cs in order to get GL defined), but like I say, how do I add the reference to OpenTK for the project that contains MainPage.xaml.cs.

Thanks for any help,
Mitch.

----- EDIT -----

Thanks to the poster for helping me so far, the new problem is a reference to System.Private.Core that cannot be resolved. Here's the my full workflow for creating this error:

1: Create a new project.

[image]

[image]

This gives me the three projects:

[image]

2: Change to .NET standard 2.1 in the OGLMobile project:

[image]

The .Android and .iOS projects don't have a .NET choice option.

3: Add reference to OpenTK to OGLMobile project:

[image]

4: OGLMobile project builds fine but .Android project gives:

[image]

If I remove reference to OpenTK everything builds again. Makes no difference if I add OpenTK Nuget package to .Android project, I still get the same error.

So close,
thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install Nuget Package **OpenTK.Graphics**, then can use that.

[image]

Now can refer it:

[image]

Note: `4.0.1` of **OpenTK.Graphics** need **.NET Standard** `2.1`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your hellp. Things are almost working but after adding the Nuget Package OpenTK.Graphics my .Android project gives the following compilation error: Can not resolve reference: "System.Private.Core" referenced by "OpenTK.Graphics". Please see my edits to original post where I have added pictures.

Comment: @user3738290 Hi, `OpenTK.Graphics` Nuget Package is only used for Xamarin Froms, you could not install it in Android/iOS. Your shared document is the way to use OpenGL in Xamarin Froms, only need to install it in Xamarin Forms you will works in iOS/Android. If the reply is helpful, please do not forget to accept it as answer( click the ✔ in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I finally have it working. I made a new project, added reference to OpenTK via References->add reference in the .Android project and then just Typed GL.ClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0f); in the OGLMobile project and then intellisense offered to add the reference to OpenTK-1.0.dll. That got things working.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the exact same issue but I can't get rid of the "error XA2002: Can not resolve reference: `System.Private.CoreLib`, referenced by `OpenTK.Graphics`" message after I add the reference to OpenTK-1.0.
Note that the missing reference is "CoreLib" as it's "Core" in the original post.
I tried to rebuild a new project twice with no success; is there anything else to do than to add the OpenTk.Graphics nuget package and to reference OpenTK that I don't see here. Thank you

Comment: @PhM75 Hi, the referenced version of `OpenTK` seems too old, you could update to the latest version to check. If there is other problems, you could ask a new question in SO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @JuniorJiang-MSFT. The only OpenTK-1.0.dll I found is located in '...\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4' and I can't find how to install/download a more recent version of it in a more recent version of the framework.

Comment: @PhM75 You could check the Nuget Package manager whether exists this nuget.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/nuget-walkthrough?view=vsmac-2019